# html reconstruct/save user state of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a website and i want to consult with you about a situation i have,

the website is kinda "advanced", dynamically build(python/javascipt/jQ), multiple forms, some of them i check in client side, some i cant, so only in server side,

the problem is that i want to save some of the state the user have, so when the response is back from the server, for example in case of failure for one of the forms, the filled fields will be still fill,or the scroll bar(inside a big table for example) will be in the same offset the user put it in..

whats the best way to do it? of course i don't want to read all those things before the submit and set them back in the returning page

thanks for the help
Jack

Comment: " i don't want to read all those things before the submit and set them back in the returning page ", how else do you expect to do it? Consider putting the data into an object and `JSON.stringify` into `sessionStorage`, with reverse for setting it back https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Comment: maybe something(cookie?) that auto store user data in client side(browser feature?) , so if he go back to that form, it will fill with his previous filled information .. is there such a thing? or i messing things togheter...

Comment: As I said, take a look at JavaScript's sessionStorage